# What is the range for the grenade launcher attachment?

Tags: call-of-duty-series

I've been looking at the stats for COD weapons on Symthic and the wiki but can't find the range stats for the underslung grenade launcher. The only thing that's listed is the explosion radius. I want to know if the grenade launcher attachment shoots grenades further than throwing a frag (about 25m). Is this listed anywhere or how can I find this distance out?

Comment: Which CoD? I'm assuming MWR, but I think it differs between games.

Comment: I'd be happy for any stats at all, but MWR or Black Ops 2 would be great.

Comment: I can certainly tell you that in COD4 or Black Ops 2, the grenade launcher *definitely* shoots farther than what you can throw.  You can pretty much shoot across the map and still get a kill if you know where to aim, such as in [this video](https://youtu.be/_u-yvC_94uc).

Comment: I suggest you refine your answer to a specific Call of Duty game, since there are so many, this question requires a pretty broad answer.

Comment: Many mechanics are similar enough among CoD games that it's possible that the range for the 203 grenade launcher is similar if not identical across most or all of the games. Couldn't say what it is without some research, though. Far.

Comment: @TimmyJim although in CoD4 you can throw grenades from anywhere on any map so they aren't exactly short range

Comment: The Call of Duty fandom wiki [page for the 203](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/M203) has a breakdown of changes from one CoD to another. Nowhere is a change in range mentioned. It also doesn't say what the range is.

Comment: Based on my research I haven't been able to find this info for any COD game, which is why I haven't tagged a specific one. I assume this mechanic's stayed largely the same, like many other mechanics in COD over the years. The only part of this that's changed is the lethal radius. If anyone is able to find these stats for a specific game I can add the relevant tag. Seems strange to me that this info isn't available anywhere, even the crossbow range stats are available.